# How to get windows credentials from browser via Angularjs app and using them in the service level?

Tags: c#, angularjs, authentication, asp.net-web-api, azure-devops

I have been scratching my head how to solve the issue described below.

So, the company where I work uses Visual Studio Team Services (was Visual Studio Online), and it is integrated/connected to our AD, meaning that If I log in to my workstation I can log in to Team Services without authenticating myself, like SSO.

I'm going to create an application which communicates to Team Services via Team Services SOAP and WebApi clients and here is the problem. I need a user to be able to communicate with Team Services and doing stuff (reading data, creating work items, creating test suits, etc.). I see little chance to convince IT to create a user only for this. They going to reject my request due to security risks.

The application architecture looks this:

- **browser**: angularjs application, spa, calling only the WebApi service
- **server**: WebApi service, which is responsible to communicate with Team Services and transforming data back and forth between the client and Team Services.
- **database**: persisting data for later analysis

There is an idea in my mind, where I can get somehow the windows credentials from the OS and push it down to the server which uses it to communicate with Team Services. In Team Services, we will see that the particular user did things.

The question, how is possible that? The articles I have found searching for something similar, always mention .Net MVC app where I need to modify the web.config in order to get the credentials. But, in my architecture there is no .Net MVC app running on local machines. There is only a SPA running in browsers.

Or my architecture is not fit for this purpose? Shall I rework it and using MVC app to be able to get the credentials and working with them? But, the question still stands, how can I pass the credentials through the calls calling Team Services?

Do you know blog entries dealing with cases like above?

Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a bit of confusion over your terms. The SPA (Single Page App) has javascript code delivered by the server to the browser that calls the .NET WebApi code. In order to get the browser to use Kerberos/Windows Authentication you need to add

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
</system.web>
```

to your web.config on the server where the .NET app is running (under IIS).

From here...
http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/integrated-windows-authentication

"On the client side, Integrated Windows authentication works with any browser that supports the Negotiate authentication scheme, which includes most major browsers. For .NET client applications, the HttpClient class supports Windows authentication:"

Then the browser will do the rest for you and the HttpContext.CurrentUser in the .NET code on the server will be set to the windows user of the clients browser.

Comment: I accept your answer because it helped a lot to put the definition to their places. Since then I understood that it is not possible to pass over the credentials, or it requires Kerberos which I don't have.